# Grep and ignore minified javascript

Tags: grep, minify, ack

Is there a way to tell ack/grep to ignore minified Javascript? Those files have thousands of characters per line and screw up the search output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ack 1.x does not have a way to ignore minified javascript directly. This will be addressed in ack 2.0.  We're working on it at http://github.com/petdance/ack2 .

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
grep foo $(find -name '*.js' -exec file {} \; | grep -v "long lines" | sed 's/:.*//')
```

- `find -name '*.js'` finds all the .js files in the current directory and subdirectories.
- Adding `-exec file {} \;` to the `find` command runs the `file` command on each result.
- The results of `file` are piped into `grep`, and files listed as having "long lines" are removed from the results.
- The descriptions from `file` are stripped off with `sed`, leaving only the filenames. These are the files `grep` will search for "foo."

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you can somehow indicate which files should be excluded. If you follow the `.min.js` convention, for instance, then it is a simple matter of just making sure these files are not searched. 
Otherwise no, grep does not have a `--maximum-number-of-characters-per-line-to-count-as-a-match` option.